# Error opening System>Configuration>Catalog in backend

Tags: magento-1.9

When trying to open System>Configuration>Catalog I get an error which produces the following error report:

> a:5:{i:0;s:87:"Invalid config field backend model: catalog/system_config_backend_catalog_category_flat";i:1;s:1660:"#0 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(328): Mage::throwException('Invalid config ...')
>   #1 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(229): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initFields(Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
>   #2 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(164): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->_initGroup(Object(Varien_Data_Form), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
>   #3 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Edit.php(92): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initForm()
>   #4 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php(107): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Edit->initForm()
>   #5 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction()
>   #6 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
>   #7 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>   #8 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>   #9 /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>   #10 /var/www/html/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
>   #11 {main}";s:3:"url";s:90:"/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/catalog/key/10c99ce673e69a7ece470ddd0411f6dd/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}

The only reference I could find to this online was [here](http://www.learnmagento.org/magento-bug-fixes/invalid-config-field-backend-model-catalogsystem_config_backend_catalog_product_flat/) and it didn't work for me.

This doesn't happen with any of the other sections of the Configuration menu.

P.S. Tried Woolfie's suggestion below (see comment) and this didn't find the problem either.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This could be a local/community module with errors in the etc/system.xml file that is used to specify system configuration options. Consider disabling modules by editing them in app/etc/modules and then re-enabling them until you find the problem module. You can also use 'lint' tools on the system.xml files to see if one of them has an error. Remember to remover files in var/cache and var/session to make sure the error is not cached.

Comment: Woolfie, this is an answer, no comment :-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_System_Config_Backend_Catalog_Category_Flat`. Check if this file exists: `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/System/Config/Backend/Catalog/Category/Flat.php`.
If it does not exist get it from a clean magento instance.